# How to add a label component in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to develop an add on for google calendar  using google app script
I am totally new to google app script 
I am unable to find how to set a label component in gas
I just need to add a label as a title of the division

Comment: What is a label in the context of Google Calendar? The term "label" is used in Gmail, but I'm not aware of it in Calendar.

Comment: @Diego is here, you are in good hands(how have you been diego?). But yes, you need to be more specific by what you mean by, label, component and division. This page will help us speak in the same terms: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar

Comment: I meant just a text for the title for add ons

Comment: Hello @kirtivyas, could you be more explicit of what you want to achieve? Cheers!

Comment: For an add on I have used CardService.newTextInput for achieving text inputs.Likewise is there any method for setting a text for title . Like <label> tag in XML

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the `title` of a text input you can just use `.setTitle()`, like this:

```
var textInput = CardService.newTextInput()
    .setFieldName("text_input_form_input_key")
    .setTitle("The title of the text input");
```

Moreover, you can check this link since it might be of help to you:

- [Card Service Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service)

Comment: I need to set an independent label . Not for the input . And I have already checked the above page . I am not able to find any method by which I can achieve my functionality

Comment: Hello @kirtivyas so you don't want the label to be linked to any component, you just want a text label? If so, why don't you use `CardService.newTextParagraph()`?